# How to use my Apple Remote Control with Windows 10

Tags: windows, remote-control

I want to use my Apple Remote Control 2G (aluminum with black buttons) in presentations on my work computer (MSI GL62M 7RD-429XES Intel Core i7-7700HQ/8GB/1TB+256SSD/GTX1050/15.6")

I have installed Bootcamp driver called `AppleRemoteInstaller64`in my PC (Windows 10), but I can not make it work. I can't connect the device to my computer.

Do you have any idea about this?

Thank in advance

PD: Yes, I know that I should do my presentations on my Mac :P

**UPDATE:** MSI GL62M 7RD-429XES Intel Core i7-7700HQ/8GB/1TB+256SSD/GTX1050/15.6"

**UPDATE 2:** I can't use yet my Apple Remote Contol 2G in Windows 10. Other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Best I can find is that is a BootCamp driver - designed to make the remote work on a Mac inside Windows, not to make it work on some random PC. Where did it come from?

Comment: I have installed AppleRemoteInstaller64 from BootCamp drivers

Comment: Although I like the ingenuity of this question this isn't something you could take to the apple store and expect them to get working.  It is slightly misfit for the site.  Superuser may be a better fit not sure.  Either way I hope you get it working.  My advice is to use an Apple Remote Equivalent.

Comment: Hehehehe. I ask this because I have the remote control and I want to use with my work computer, that is the computer that I use usually to do presentations. But I know the difficulty to use an Apple device in a Microsoft computer

Answer (score 4):

You can use http://www.eventghost.org/ to map the infrared receiver to forward the Apple Remote's buttons to keyboard presses within Windows.

See also https://superuser.com/questions/278951/my-keyboard-has-no-media-keys-can-i-control-media-without-them

Quoted from http://gegensystem.blogspot.de/2013/11/using-apple-remote-for-power-point-on.html :

> Download: http://www.eventghost.org/
>
> Don´t forget to support this project if you are satisfied with it.
>
> First klick on configuration (Konfiguration) - then add an PlugIn -
>   choose Generic HID for your Apple remote.
>
> By clicking some of the keys of the remote, eventghost now shows the
>   keyentries of them.
>
> Build a new macro belonging to emulated keyboard entry (Emulierte
>   Tastatureingabe) and choose (for example) LEFT. Now drag and drop the
>   Keyentry of your remote to the new macro and the key on the remote is
>   now connected to this new event.
>
> I connected the LEFT key and the RIGHT key to the LEFT arrow and the
>   RIGHT arrow of apples remote. Now it is possible to use the remote to
>   control the power point presentation. Be aware that you have to start
>   eventghost manually or drop it into yout autostart directory. Without
>   it running in the background, the system can only work with the
>   predifined remote actions!

Comment: The problem is that I can't connect my Apple Remote to my computer

Comment: Can you please specify which version of the Apple Remote you want to use? (Apple Remote 1G (white plastic), Apple Remote 2G (aluminum with black buttons), Siri Remote (black glass with aluminum back))

Comment: Ok, I update my question

Comment: @jjmartinez Can you let us know the PC/laptop you want to use it with? Has it a built-in IR receiver or do you use a separate one?

Comment: It's a MSI Laptop: MSI GL62M 7RD-429XES Intel Core i7-7700HQ/8GB/1TB+256SSD/GTX1050/15.6"